# Why would we use different output and recurrent activations in an LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow, software

I am developing a LSTM network with Tensorflow. The Tensorflow [LSTM documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) shows that there are different activations for the output of the timestep (tanh) and for the data flowing back in to the network at the next time step (sigmoid). It seems to me that we would want the same activation function for both of these, so the fact that they default to different things is surprising to me.

So why would we want to use different activations and recurrent activations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435316/rigorous-logic-of-lstm/435331#435331

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica yes! Thank you! It links to the most intuitive explanation of LSTMs I've seen!